# Arrange divs like images?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a navigation bar (`#nav`), and have each nav item be a div (`#nav div`). This doesn't work well, however. Here's what I'm trying:

```
#nav {
    background: url("navbg.png"); /* navbg.png is 1x40 pixels */
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url("Selected.png"); /* Selected.png is 200x40 pixels */
    text-align: center;
}
```

When I do this with two divs in the `#nav` div, one shows up on the left, and one is below. When I do this, but with `display: inline;` in `#nav div`, it's centered, but the divs don't have any background, and the text in the two divs show up side-by-side.

I'd like the divs to work like images, being affected by `text-align: center;` and showing up side-by-side.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using DIVs for this rather than the most popular method of using a UL with LIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` or `float: left` on `#nav div`

Comment: Inline-Block is not supported in  < IE 7. use with caution http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block

Comment: @RayHughes even with DOCTYPE?

Comment: doctype just tells the browser what type of document to expect (XHTML HTML Etc.) Not how to render it. In HTML 5 a DTD is not required. Also, I recommend you check out hml boiler plate. It has a lot of cross browser fixes

Answer (score 2):

The `display: inline-block` style rule will do the trick, but it has some drawbacks. See [CSS display: inline-block: why it rocks, and why it sucks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) for more details.

I might also suggest using a list instead of divs for navigation elements. That's a common strategy which results in (hopefully) clearer markup.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise using a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) solution on your outer div `#div`. Then `float:left` on all the `#nav div` children.